# Markdown is not being rendered on Jekyll Site?

Tags: jekyll

Markdown is not being convertedto HTML.

**_config.yml**

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
    input: GFM
# Permalinks
permalink:        pretty
encoding:         UTF-8
```

**output in frontend**

```
<article class="post-content">
<!-- Contents of md files here in plain text-->
</article>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the [kramdown Syntax](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks) you have to enable parsing of markdown in html-block elements. There are two ways to do this:

**Globally**: in your _config.yml add:

```
kramdown:  
  parse_block_html: true
```

or at the beginning of your markdown document (not in yaml-header) set:

```
{::options parse_block_html="true" /}
```

**Locally**: add `markdown="1"` to your html-block, to get the markdown inside the block rendered.

So in your case that would read:

```
<article markdown="1" class="post-content">
<!-- Contents of md files here in plain text-->
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this line:

`markdown_ext: "markdown, mkdown, mkdn, mkd, md"`

which was messing it up